# How do you call this kind if pop-up view?

Tags: ios, uiview

I've downloaded an app that uses this kind of pop-up view for a menu, that means when you click on a row in a menu, one of those views is opening up and you can choose your settings. How do I make these and what are they called?

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Do you want to know about Action sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Action Sheet.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/action-sheets/

Developer refrence is https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller

**Update**
Please note that we don't provide code, you have to try yourself then we can help with any raised issues.

Comment: thank you! sure, I just found it a great idea but didn't find anything about those action sheets on german google (propably because I didn't know what to look for)